# Which structure to use to parse data in JSON?

Tags: json, swift, xcode, parsing, networking

I am very new to using JSON and I'm trying to figure it out the best solution to parse the below data into my app using swift. So far I've been successfully creating structures to parse the data into my apps but with this API I'm getting a bit confused.

The path of the value i'm looking returns: 0.price

Below the JSON i'm working on - i need a structure to retrieve the 'price' value - i understand it is a swift dictionary nested into an array but I really don't know how to create this structure to get the 0.price value.

```
[
    {
        "id": "BTC",
        "currency": "BTC",
        "symbol": "BTC",
        "name": "Bitcoin",
        "logo_url": "https://s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/nomics-api/static/images/currencies/btc.svg",
        "price": "9397.86203481",
        "price_date": "2020-07-09T00:00:00Z",
        "price_timestamp": "2020-07-09T05:10:00Z",
        "circulating_supply": "18427462",
        "max_supply": "21000000",
        "market_cap": "173178745528",
        "rank": "1",
        "high": "19343.01808710",
        "high_timestamp": "2017-12-16T00:00:00Z",
        "1d": {
            "volume": "19780482959.23",
            "price_change": "55.47211721",
            "price_change_pct": "0.0059",
            "volume_change": "1974758604.83",
            "volume_change_pct": "0.1109",
            "market_cap_change": "1030908096.99",
            "market_cap_change_pct": "0.0060"
        },
        "30d": {
            "volume": "663105718213.57",
            "price_change": "-472.08068928",
            "price_change_pct": "-0.0478",
            "volume_change": "-451402235448.26",
            "volume_change_pct": "-0.4050",
            "market_cap_change": "-8416909381.05",
            "market_cap_change_pct": "-0.0463"
        }
    }
]
```

Thanks,

Max

Comment: You must have tried or researched something, please show us your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use **`Codable`** to parse the above *JSON response*.

**`Codable` Models:**

**Option-1 :** If you want to parse all data

```
struct Response: Codable {
    let id, currency, symbol, name: String
    let logoUrl: String
    let price: String
    let priceDate, priceTimestamp: String
    let circulatingSupply, maxSupply, marketCap, rank: String
    let high: String
    let highTimestamp: String
    let the1D, the30D: The1_D

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case id, currency, symbol, name, logoUrl, price, priceDate, priceTimestamp, circulatingSupply, maxSupply, marketCap, rank, high, highTimestamp
        case the1D = "1d"
        case the30D = "30d"
    }
}

struct The1_D: Codable {
    let volume, priceChange, priceChangePct, volumeChange: String
    let volumeChangePct, marketCapChange, marketCapChangePct: String

}
```

**Option-2:** In case you just need the `price` value and ignore everything else,

```
struct Response: Codable {
    let price: String
}
```

**Parse** the *JSON* `data` like so,

```
do {
    let decoder = JSONDecoder()
    decoder.keyDecodingStrategy = .convertFromSnakeCase
    let response = try decoder.decode([Response].self, from: data)
    let price = response.first?.price //Get the value of price here..
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```